# what is the best tool to profile asp.net mvc code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, profiling

Are there any good free or trial tool to use to profile performance bottlenecks in asp.net mvc c# code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET code profiling tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312493/net-code-profiling-tools) or 4061555 or 2650766

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473666/tips-for-optimizing-c-net-programs/2474118#2474118

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to profile C# code you can use [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/) or [dotTrace 4 Performance](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)

Answer (score 1):

Redgate has a lot of great tools, I've worked quite a lot with them:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

[Any decent C# profilers out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-profilers-out-there) - try here =)

Answer (score 0):

There is the free [EQATEC Profiler](http://eqatec.com/profiler/) for performance profiling .NET code