# Is there a way to get the number of currently open SPRequests in code?

Tags: sharepoint

Being able to see the count of SPRequests would be pretty useful for debugging, so - is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excellent question, it's really annoying to see these warnings in the ULS logs (C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\12\LOGS)

The SPRequest warning is usually related to undisposed SPWeb or SPSite objects, the best way to avoid this is by doing

```
using(SPWeb or SPSite instance)
{
    //some code
}
```

The using statement takes care of disposing the objects properly.

There are some tools available to help you out, e.g. [SPDisposeCheck](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck)

More info on this on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248.aspx

Comment: SPDisposeCheck helps, but sadly not always. I was hoping someone could perhaps know about an undocumented method or something like that. Well, one can dream. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would say your best bet for looking at that would be to use a memory profiling tool. Not only should you be able to see the count, but depending on the tool you can see a stack trace of where objects were allocated.

Theres a few out there, for example check out this post

[.NET Memory Profiling Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399847/net-memory-profiling-tools)