# Finding a .NET Memory Leak?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks

I have created a sample program, with 2 Dialogs. Both Dialogs have a picture box, one calls pictureBox1.Image.Dispose(); in the protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) method and the other doesn't.

When you run the program and use the Task Manager to look at the memory usage, it becomes *very* obvious that the dialog that does not call pictureBox1.Image.Dispose(); leaks memory really badly.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a tool that would show up the problem in such a clear way?

Is there any way to count memory allocation/deallocation for a particular c# source file? At least this was something I was able to do with unmanaged C++.

Comment: You could just try the trial of any .net memory profiler software like from RedGate or Jetbrains.

Comment: Have you tried the profiler built into Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: There are lots of good tools for profiling memory. Here's a previous writeup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399847/net-memory-profiling-tools

Comment: @PaulKearney-pk this thread is badly outdated, tools evolved in passed 10 years

Answer (score 10):

In VS2010 try the `Analyze` > `Launch Performance Wizard` menu option and choose the memory option.

In VS2017 it is `Analyze` > `Performance Profiler...`

Comment: I have tried the profiler built into Visual Studio 2010, did not find it particularly helpful unfortunately.

Comment: Did you turn on the "Also collect .NET object lifetime data" option?

Answer (score 4):

Check out Ants Profiler: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

There is a 14 day free trial and lots of helpful tutorials to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

As **alternative** to the embedded performance profiler of VS, I find Jetbrains' **DotMemory** practical and easy.

- You can see very quickly which objects types, from managed code that are leaking.
- You got a dashboard with a view on common problems (string duplicates etc)
- You also have a view on the **unmanaged memory**. The interface is rather
  complete, complex (you can really dig and understand many things, and find quickly the culprit objects and code).
  [image: a view on a snapshot analysis]
  [0] https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/