# Console.WriteLine and Memory Leaks

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, console, console.writeline

I'm trying to reduce the memory usage of a console application I have. It is supposed to run for hours on end, but it seems like the memory usage is gradually increasing with each second. It does use multiple threads, and does a variety of things, but I read somewhere that having a lot of calls to Console.WriteLine can also cause memory spikes.

Because the application is constantly writing to the console, I thought that maybe the memory usage is because of this. Unfortunately, I can't easily clear the console because I'm redirecting the output to a monitoring window. I've turned it off temporarily, but the memory is still increasing, which tells me there's other things I need to address.

Before I go about hunting down memory leaks, I was wondering if anyone can confirm/verify whether having thousands of Console.WriteLine's could cause a memory leak, or if that's already handled appropriately by the redirected output buffer. I've tried to do a search, but haven't found much on this.

Comment: What makes you think that what you're seeing is a leak?  Memory usage may well increase until there's enough pressure to warrant a collection; depending on your code and the environment it's running in, this could be a long time.  How much memory is leaking per second, and what is the application doing?  `Console.WriteLine` shouldn't consume any more memory than the message occupies in the buffer, unless there's something I've missed...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399847/net-memory-profiling-tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having thousands of calls to `Console.WriteLine` does not cause a memory leak. I have a long-running program (it's been up for 6 months now) that writes a few hundred lines per minute to the console, and its memory usage has remained level.

It's *possible* that writing thousands of lines infrequently all at once can cause memory spikes  due to temporary strings, but those will be collected the next time GC is run. But a steady load of `Console.WriteLine` will just cause a steady memory load of uncollected strings. It won't be ever-increasing.

Comment: Actually, that isn't always true.  While Console.WriteLine is thread safe, if you do call it from multiple threads, you will get a handle leak where Events/Semaphores on other threads will not close.  I have verified this in Win2003 .NET 4.  I have not tried other platforms yet.