# Causes of clr ! JIT_New in PerfView CPU stack

Tags: c#, .net, performance, perfview

I am using PerfView to tune an application, and the second most expensive item is currently tagged as:

> OTHER < < clr!JIT_New > >

at over 10% of CPU. This continues even for subsequent runs of the test case.

Can anyone identify what activities or code practices might be causing the dynamic generation of new code requiring JIT-ting?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JIT_New() is a helper function inside the CLR that runs whenever you create a new object in your code with the *new* operator.  It just allocates memory from the garbage collected heap and calls the class constructor.  Or in other words, it implements the Opcodes.Newobj IL instruction.  Its name is a bit confusing, it doesn't have anything to do with jitting your code.  Just a helper function that the jitter knows about, it compiles a call to this helper function directly into the generated machine code.  JIT_Newarr1() would be another one you'd encounter, it allocates an array.

I don't know PerfView, do note that the execution time for JIT_New() *may* include the time needed to perform garbage collections.  Which occur when the gen#0 heap is full when JIT_New() runs.  Which would explain the large percentage, JIT_New() is otherwise extremely fast.  Nothing much you can do about it, this is fixed overhead in any managed program.

Comment: If your assumption that `JIT_New()` includes the time taken for garbage collection is correct (and I believe it is), then it's not strictly true that there's "nothing much you can do about it": in many cases, it's worthwhile running the program under a good [memory profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399847/net-memory-profiling-tools) and figure out how to create fewer objects (i.e., less garbage). A high "% time in GC" performance counter can be indicative of a poorly-written program.

Comment: Thank you. I do not believe any garbage collection is included; I am creating a large number of small temporary objects that I might be able to convert into `struct`s instead. Do you happen to know if a boxing overhead is incurred to implement IEquatable<T> on a struct? I saw something recently that suggested so.

Comment: @BradleyGraingerL On reflection, you are probably correct. I will check out this aspect of the design.