# Strange function slowing down my program

Tags: vb.net, performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio's performance analysis to determine why my program is slow. The function that takes up 25% of the exclusive CPU samples is a function  in clr.dll called

`?JIT_New@@YIPAVObject@@PAUCORINFO_CLASS_STRUCT_@@@Z`

What does this mean? (I'm using Visual Basic 2012 if that matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is essentially the same as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908585/causes-of-clr-jit-new-in-perfview-cpu-stack).

Short answer: JIT_New is allocating memory, and maybe occasionally getting hit with the garbage collection time.

Comment: Hmmm, that makes sense, I do have a lot of GC going on. But I wonder, what could YIPAVObject and PAUCORINFO_CLASS_STRUCT stand for?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I saw the exact same identifiers in a C# program that created a class called "Foo" 100,000,000 times, so it's not related to the naming of anything in your assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting hit by excessive boxing (hence 'struct').